# Gett attachment link using javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I can download attachments from an email account using JavaMail API. But is there any way to get the download links of the attachments of an email using Java?

For my purpose, I need to get the download links of the attachments and provide them to user. So that the user can download those attachments directly from email server. I will highly appreciate any other kind of suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The attachments in the email are the integral part of an email. It is just another `MIME` part in the email. You won't be able to get directly the attachment as a web resource.

To do so you can parse the email and store the attachment on the filestore  and then provide it as a web resource.